# INSERT INTO based on WHERE clause of second table

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables

```
table1
+--------+-----+------+
|  DATE  |  VAR|   VAL|
+--------+-----+------+
|20160101|VAR_1|   0.4|
|20160101|VAR_2|   0.1|
|20160102|VAR_1|   0.6|
|20160102|VAR_2|   0.1|
|20160103|VAR_1|   0.5|
|20160103|VAR_2|   0.1|
+--------+-----+------+

table 2
+--------+-----+------+
|  DATE  |  VAR|   VAL|
+--------+-----+------+
|20160102|VAR_1|   0.6|
|20160102|VAR_2|   0.1|
|20160103|VAR_1|   0.5|
|20160103|VAR_2|   0.1|
|20160104|VAR_1|   0.3|
|20160104|VAR_2|   0.2|
|20160105|VAR_1|   0.2|
|20160105|VAR_2|   0.6|
|20160106|VAR_1|   0.3|
|20160106|VAR_2|   0.4|
+--------+-----+------+
```

What I want to do is add all the new entries of the table2 into table1 based on the date. My idea was like this

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE date > (SELECT MAX(date) from table1);
```

but I get a syntax error.
With a NOT IN it works...

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.date NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT date from table1);
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Does it matter that you have table2.data in the second one but not the first one?  Did you get any detail in the error?  Edit:  Remove the Insert and do just the select.  See what you get.

Comment: It works in Postgres. Please edit your post to attach error message for first insert statement. Also, are you storing your dates within varchar column? If that is the case consider switching it to a proper datatype.

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting.

Comment: Are you using Hive? Hive uses a SQL-like language called HiveQL which is loosely modeled after MySQL but has many differences from standard SQL.

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs using Hive. I forgot to mention that in the question and had it only in the tags.
The error message is:
`Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:530 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'MAX' '(' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way try this , I used date1 instead of date

```
select t2.* from table2 t2, (SELECT MAX(date1) date1 FROM table1 ) t1 where t2.date1 > t1.date1;
```